# Why wont UIView display a second time?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to figure out why my newDogView will only present once. This app takes a dog photo, stores it in a struct with some other info, and plots that dog on a map view as an annotation. When you press the newDogButton, a UIImagePickerController is presented. Once it's dismissed, a preview shows up with some options to add info.

Once the user submits the dog photo, everything is saved to a struct. The problem is that when the user taps the newDogButton a second time, the newDogView is never made visible again.

I think it might have something to do with the way I'm calling .removeFromSuperview().

Please let me know if anything stands out. I'm new to this!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

var image: UIImage?
var location: CLLocation?
var dogs: [Dog] = []
@IBOutlet var newDogButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var newDogScore: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var newDogName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var newDogView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var preview: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!
let locman = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locman.delegate = self
    self.locman.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locman.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.map.mapType = .standard
    self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    self.map.userTrackingMode = .follow
    self.newDogName.delegate = self

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}

@IBAction func newDogTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    presentCamera()
    self.locman.requestLocation()
}

func presentCamera() {
    let source = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
    guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(source)
        else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Camera Error", message: "Oops! Looks like Dog Spotter doesn't have access to your camera! Please open Settings to give Dog Spotter permission to use the camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            present(alert, animated: true)
            return
    }
    let camera = UIImagePickerController()
    camera.sourceType = source
    camera.delegate = self
    camera.allowsEditing = true

    self.present(camera, animated: true)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        image = editedImage
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        self.setupNewDogView()
    })
}

func setupNewDogView() {
    newDogView.isHidden = true
    map.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    view.addSubview(newDogView)
    newDogView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    newDogView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: -50).isActive = true
    newDogView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1, constant: -200).isActive = true
    newDogView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    newDogView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    preview.image = self.image
    newDogView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    newDogButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    newDogView.isHidden = false
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let loc = locations.last!
    let coord = loc.coordinate
    location = loc
    print("You are at \(coord.latitude) \(coord.longitude)")
}

@IBAction func submitDog(_ sender: Any) {
    let newDog = Dog(name: newDogName.text!, score: Int(newDogScore.text!)!, picture: image!, location: location!)
    dogs.append(newDog)
    print(dogs.last!)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.newDogView.alpha = 0
    }) { _ in
        self.newDogView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.map.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    return
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

}

[Here's an image of my storyboard, if that's helpful!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBcC3.png)

Here's the console output when trying to display the view twice.

> 2017-08-10 16:27:59.263965-0700 DogSpotter[960:682273]  - changing property contentsGravity in transform-only layer, will have no effect
>   2017-08-10 16:27:59.264702-0700 DogSpotter[960:682273]  - changing property contentsGravity in transform-only layer, will have no effect
>   2017-08-10 16:27:59.374063-0700 DogSpotter[960:682273] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 960 (DogSpotter) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
>   2017-08-10 16:27:59.374151-0700 DogSpotter[960:682273] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see )
>   2017-08-10 16:28:03.321761-0700 DogSpotter[960:682273] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
>   2017-08-10 16:28:03.322541-0700 DogSpotter[960:682273] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
>   >
>   You are at 45.4874888481593 -122.734139806728
>   Dog(name: "Rex", score: 11, picture:  size {750, 750} orientation 0 scale 1.000000, location: <+45.48748885,-122.73413981> +/- 65.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 8/10/17, 4:28:07 PM Pacific Daylight Time)
>   >
>   2017-08-10 16:28:44.979563-0700 DogSpotter[960:682273] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
>   2017-08-10 16:28:44.981668-0700 DogSpotter[960:682273] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
>   You are at 45.4874600607505 -122.734123729821

Comment: add a debugPrint(newDogView) before this line `view.addSubview(newDogView)`and let me know what prints after the second time

Comment: @ReinierMelian '<UIView: 0x100d0a950; frame = (25 100; 325 467); alpha = 0; hidden = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x174027a80>>
2017-08-10 16:28:44.979563-0700 DogSpotter[960:682273] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction'

Comment: Did I paste the right thing? These comments are really limited by length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your self.newDogView.alpha back to 1 in setupNewDogView() 
and dont use removeFromSuperView, you are lost the reference to the view.

Comment: instead of removefromsuperview, what should I use?

Comment: If you were creating the view programmatically you could remove it and then add it again, but using IBoutlet if you remove it you lose the pointer to the view. Considering that you always have to use it, I do not see problems just using isHidden. Is this creating any problem for you?

Comment: Or move to out  the screen.